# Security for React front-end and Node back-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, auth0

I'm relatively new to the modern JavaScript web development world. I've built a very simple Node/Express back-end and a separate React front-end. My vague plan is to have users that will have permission to access certain areas of the front-end, and then have the front-end make requests to the back-end. Can the front-end and back-end share the same authentication/authorization scheme? Can they both use something like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/)? How can I make these two secure?

I'm a little stuck and would appreciate any advice or a nudge in the right direction. I'm mostly stuck because these are two separate applications but the same "user" would technically have permissions to certain React views as well as certain Express endpoints - how they moosh together?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although seems not directly related to your topic, but I would actually suggest you try Meteor if you are not planning to immediately start working on large projects (not pressing too hard on scalability).

Meteor has a builtin support for Accounts and interacts with MongoDB nicely, and it also has its own DDP protocol that simplifies API call massively. It also interacts nicely with React.

If you think Meteor might not be a good choice for yourself, you could still learn from its design policies of authorization, etc. It has quite a bit package source code that are not too difficult to understand, and should be helpful for you to learn the basic idea. (Actually, Meteor's `Accounts` package already implements the basic idea mentioned by another answerer, you can learn from its design principles)

Answer (score 0):

When users log in to your site, issue them with an access token that they keep client side. On front-end, check if user has token and correct permissions before rendering components. On back-end, send the token as request headers to the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a similar case, but with the spring boot kotlin at the backend instead. My solution is using JWT token to validate the authentication and authorization.

1. User logins by input login form and send POST method to backend via a REST API.Backend validates credential and returns the JWT token including encrypted     user_role, expiration date, etc... if valid or `403 exception`
2. Front-end decodes the JWT (using `jwt-decode` lib or something else),
   save it to validate the access permission to specific page in the
   website based on user_role. Eg: role='ADMIN' can access to admin dashboard page, role='USER' can access user profile page, etc.

If you use express as the backend, I suggest to use the feathersjs. It has backend solutions for this and an optional front end version. Refer: https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/jwt.html

Answer (score 0):

Secure Front end (React.js) and Back end (Node.js/Express Rest API) with Keycloak [follow this](https://medium.com/@chamith/secure-front-end-react-js-and-back-end-node-js-express-rest-api-with-keycloak-daf159f0a94e)